# What do python sockets do with EINTR?

Tags: python, sockets

So far my networking code works fine, but I'm a bit worried about something I hid under the carpet:

The man pages for `accept`, `close`, `connect`, `recv` and `send` mention that `errno.EINTR` can show up when a system call was interrupted by a signal.

I am quite clueless here.

What does python do with that ?  Does it automatically retry the call, does it raise a socket.error with that errno ?  What is the appropriate thing I should do if that exception is raised ?  Can I generate these signals myself in my unittests ?

Comment: Oh, don't know if it matters, but my sockets are non-blocking.  It's set on the socket itself, not as an argument to recv or send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python simply retries the call and hides the signal from the user (helps with cross-platform consistency where -EINTR doesn't exist). You can safely ignore the EINTR issue but if you'd like to test it anyway, it's easy to do. Just set up a blocking operation that will not return (such as a socket.accept with no incoming connection) and send the process a signal.

Comment: Not true for all syscalls though. According to this (still open) bug, Python *should* retry the call, but doesn't, in at least some relevant cases: http://bugs.python.org/issue9867 — but a comment there says “SocketIO, subprocess, multiprocessing, socket.sendall” *do* retry.